# update authorities of logged in user Spring security

Tags: spring-security

I have integrated spring security on a restful API with spring-boot,
and now I am looking for a way to update authorities of an already logged user.

I have implemented a custom user for Spring authentication !
I can get All principals (all logged in users) from the `sessionRegistry` like this way : 
        `List<Object> allPrincipals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();`

now when I try to update the authorities of a specific user, the authorities won't update I always got the same authorities until logging out and then loggin in.

Here is my code :

```
List<Object> allPrincipals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

for (Object principal : allPrincipals) {

    if (principal instanceof SpringSecurityAuthentificatedUser) {

        SpringSecurityAuthentificatedUser principalInSession = (SpringSecurityAuthentificatedUser) principal;
        if(id.equals(principalInSession.getUser().getId().toString())){

            // updating the user's authorities
            principalInSession.getUser().setRole(role);
            principalInSession.getAuthorities().clear();
            principalInSession.getAuthorities().add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));

            SpringSecurityAuthentificatedUser springSecurityAuthentificatedUser =
                    new SpringSecurityAuthentificatedUser(principalInSession.getUser(),principalInSession.getUser().getPassword(),principalInSession.getAuthorities());


            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(springSecurityAuthentificatedUser, principalInSession.getUser().getPassword(), principalInSession.getAuthorities())
            );
        }

    }
}
```

could any one help me ?

Comment: Please can you explain more , or refomlulate your question and put more code ?

Comment: @NeptuneZ I've added more code !
my question is as follow : How can I update authorities of an already logged in user ( the effects on authorities takes immediately not on the next authentification of that user  )

Comment: When you find the user that you want to update authorities for use `SessionRegistry` to get the `SessionInformation`.  This should return a `List<SessionInformation>` for the specified `Principal`(expired and active sessions, you can specify only active if needed).  Then update the `Principal` with the new authorties.  Then register the new session with the new `Principal` & `SessionId`.  (`sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(principal, sessionid)`).  I'm not sure if this works as it is formulated from just looking at the `SessionRegistry` api and not test.